# Getting value from a query

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel. I'm trying to get the objectives.id from this query but instead  it's giving me the media.id, so trying to do an 'AS' in the query so I can pass it through to the view:

```
        $objectives = DB::table('objectives')
        ->join('users', 'objectives.assigned_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->join('media', 'objectives.training_document_id', '=', 'media.model_id')
        ->where('objectives.assigned_id', '=', $assigned_id)
        ->where('media.model_type', '=', 'App\Models\TrainingDoc')
        ->distinct('objectives.id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: distinct doesnt have an arguments its just flag for query builder `distinct()->select('objectives.id')`

Comment: i'm using distinct so don't get multiple records, just not sure how to get the objectives.id vale because it gets taken over by the media.id value

Comment: You haven't selected anything, so you're selecting everything. Columns with the same name will overwrite each other. Just add a `select()` call. Is there a reason you aren't using Eloquent relationships? It would make your code much easier to deal with.

Comment: You could put it specifically in your select (`select('objectives.*', ... )`)

Comment: I'm really new to Laravel/Eloquent and this was the only way I thought to do it, not even sure where I'd put the select call. I need everything though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the distinct `objectives.id` using the query which will return distinct set of `objectives.id`s.

```
$objectives = DB::table('objectives')
->select('objectives.id')->distinct()
->join('users', 'objectives.assigned_id', '=', 'users.id')
->join('media', 'objectives.training_document_id', '=', 'media.model_id')
->where('objectives.assigned_id', '=', $assigned_id)
->where('media.model_type', '=', 'App\Models\TrainingDoc')
->get();
```

If you want to get a one record per `objectives.id` you can use `groupBy` option which will return the whole row.

```
$objectives = DB::table('objectives')
->join('users', 'objectives.assigned_id', '=', 'users.id')
->join('media', 'objectives.training_document_id', '=', 'media.model_id')
->where('objectives.assigned_id', '=', $assigned_id)
->where('media.model_type', '=', 'App\Models\TrainingDoc')
->groupBy('objectives.id')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that  doesn't return all the other values

Comment: I updated the answer to have ``groupBy`` option.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't return all the values. The problem is I want the objective.id, all the values and not have media.id overriding objectives.id which is what it is doing at the moment.

Comment: @dastuk so you need other type of join then probably `leftJoin`

Answer (score 0):

```php
foreach($objectives as $key=>$objective)
   dump($objective->id);
endforeach
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).